# In node package.json, invoke script from another script with extra parameter, in this case add mocha watcher

Tags: json, node.js, npm, mocha.js

in node's package.json I would like to reuse a command that I already have in a 'script'.

Here is the practical example

instead of (note the extra **-w** on the **watch** script):

```
"scripts": {
             "test" : "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --recursive -R list",
             "watch": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --recursive -R list -w",
           }
```

I would like to have something like

```
"scripts": {
             "test" : "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --recursive -R list",
             "watch": "npm run script test" + "-w",
           }
```

which doesn't work (can't do string concats in json), but you should get what I would like

I know that npm scripts support:
 - & (parallel execution) 
 - && (sequencial execution)

so maybe there is another option?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This can be done in `npm@2.1.17`.  You don't specify your OS and the version of `npm` that you are using, but unless you have done something to update it, you are probably running `npm@1.4.28` which does **not** support the syntax below.

On Linux or OSX you can update npm with `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`.  See https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm for a guide to updating `npm` on all platforms.

You should be able to do this by passing an additional argument to your script:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register --recursive -R list",
  "watch": "npm run test -- -w"
}
```

I verified this using the following, simplified package.json:

```
{
  "scripts": { "a": "ls", "b": "npm run a -- -l" }
}
```

Output:

```
$ npm run a

> @ a /Users/smikes/src/github/foo
> ls

package.json
$ npm run b

> @ b /Users/smikes/src/github/foo
> npm run a -- -l


> @ a /Users/smikes/src/github/foo
> ls -l

total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 smikes  staff  55  4 Jan 05:34 package.json
$
```

Comment: perfect that did it, thanks. Here is the commit with the fix https://github.com/o2platform/fluentnode/commit/a2508df1d295d17ddbea8c7ac6c204d86886409d

Comment: I was missing the "npm run" when calling another script from a script. Thanks!

Comment: TIL the `--` tells `npm run` not to look for options after the `--` (in this case `-w`).

Comment: Worth noting that in the shell (bash, zsh, etc), the `--` double dash is used by most (not all) commands to indicate 'end of options'

`man bash` gives this info:

`A -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.`

Comment: What if we use yarn and yarn is not installed npm is installed or vice versa???

Comment: @FaisalManzer this u?? :P 
https://gist.github.com/coryhouse/b26f49bead69066844d9#gistcomment-2980170